# How to click the close button within a modal window through Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

Cannot click close button class="close whitebutton"

```
<button type="button" class="close whitebutton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

Trying class_name as below, and it doesn't work, don't know why?:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "whitebutton").click()
```

Comment: if you run `btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "whitebutton")` and then run `type(btn)` what do you get?

Comment: Please show the markup of what you are trying to select.

Comment: Add url and we will try to click it.